# Scala pattern match types within JsValue

Tags: java, scala, generics, playframework, pattern-matching

So I have these two similar functions in Scala, they both convert their `JsValue` into a Java typed Number and really only differ by the specific type:

```
import play.api.lib.json._
import java.lang.{Double => JavaDouble, Integer => JavaInteger}

def getDouble(jsDouble : JsValue) : JavaDouble = {
  val strDouble : String = jsDouble.asInstanceOf[JsString].value.replace(",", "")
  val jDouble : JavaDouble = JavaDouble.valueOf(strDouble)
  jDouble
} 

def getInteger(jsInteger : JsValue) : JavaInteger = {
  val strInteger : String = jsInteger.asInstanceOf[JsString].value.replace(",", "")
  val jInteger : JavaInteger = JavaInteger.valueOf(strInteger)
  jInteger
}
```

Since they're so similar, to each other, I was hoping to combine them into one function and and use a generic type to differ the two and pattern match by type:

```
def getNumber[T](jsNumber : JsValue) : T = {
  val strNumber: String = jsNumber.asInstanceOf[JsString].value.replace(",", "")
  T.valueOf(strNumber) match {
    case typeOf[JavaInteger] => JavaInteger.valueOf(strNumber)
    case typeOf[JavaDouble] => JavaDouble.valueOf(strNumber)
    // case _ => throw a relevant Exception 
  } 
}
```

However `T.valueOf` doesn't actually work, I'm hoping there's some way I can Pattern match the type within the `JsValue` so I know what type I want to return.

Comment: what your `jsDouble : JsValue` look like?? Strange that you are converting to string and removing `","` - `jsDouble.asInstanceOf[JsString].value.replace(",", "")`.  should not your jsValue be like `JsNumber(50.8)` or `JsNumber(50)`

Comment: When it's one thousand or higher, a comma is in the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about some closures ?

```
  def getNumber[T](jsNumber : JsValue)(f : String => T) : T = {
    val strNumber: String = jsNumber.asInstanceOf[JsString].value.replace(",", "")
    f(strNumber)
  }

  def getDouble(jsDouble: JsValue): JavaDouble = {
    getNumber(jsDouble)(JavaDouble.valueOf)
  }

  def getInteger(jsInteger: JsValue): JavaInteger = {
    getNumber(jsInteger)(JavaInteger.valueOf)
  }
```

Note that at this point, the syntax `def getDouble = getNumber(_)(JavaDouble.valueOf)` is also valid, but I'm not quite sure it's really equivalent (or rather, I'm sure it's not, but I'm not sure why :D )